# Adding spaces to morses letters translation in python

Tags: python

Hello I have written this code in order to translate user input in morses alphabet and write it in a file , but I have 1 problem: It doesn't have spaces between each letter.Thank you in advance I can re-explain the problem if needed.

```
import re
  
    def txt_2_morse(msg):


        morse = {
            'A':'.-', 'B':'-...', 'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.',
            'F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....', 'I':'..', 'J':'.---',
            'K':'-.-', 'L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.', 'O':'---',
            'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-', 'R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
            'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--', 'X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--',
            'Z':'--..', '1':'.----', '2':'..---', '3':'...--', '4':'....-',
            '5':'.....', '6':'-....', '7':'--...', '8':'---..', '9':'----.',
            '0':'-----', ' ':'/'}
    
        return "".join([morse.get(c.upper(), ' ') for c in msg])
       
    
    while True:
       user_input = input('Input your hidden message!')
       regex_matcher= re.compile("/[a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]/g")
       if (regex_matcher.search(user_input)  == False ):
          user_input
       else: 
          f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
          f.write(txt_2_morse(user_input + "\n"))
          f.close()
          break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i add space after each letter/number after its written in the file

since that code that generate the file body is

```
"".join([morse.get(c.upper(), ' ') for c in msg])
```

All you need to do is to use a space instead of empty string

```
" ".join([morse.get(c.upper(), ' ') for c in msg])
```

Comment: thank you it worked,  I will mark this as the answer